# Need to create a regex expression for symbols and special characters

Tags: c#, regex

Am new to regex, and i need to create a simple regex expression that wouldn't allow alphabets, numeric and alpha numeric values. it would allow only symbols and special characters.

```
if(expression)
{
  // logic
}
```

TIA

Comment: `[^\w]+`, I suppose?

Comment: `\W+` would work if `_` (underscore) is not considered as a special char, otherwise you need `[\W_]+`

Comment: Try : [!@#$%^&*()_]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise starting learning more about regular expressions. There might be many similar questions on stack overflow.

Secondly, you can visit sites like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) where the site helps you create and test regular expressions on the fly.

Answering your question, the regex to disallow alphanumeric characters is

```
^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

The above regular expression does not allow any of the characters from 0-9 or A-Z or a-z to be present in the test string.